# Remove noise close to an object of a grayscale image

Tags: matlab

I have the image bellow that has a main object and around it there is some noise, like smoke, circled with the red line.

1. Is it possible to remove this noise keeping the main object intact as possible?
2. Can we do that **without using a manual threshold**, e.g., [look here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html) if that helps?

I would like to mention that the background does not correspond to zero values. So applying a threshold method and setting to zero the corresponding spots, based on the obtained mask,  will destroy the smoothness of the background.

Best regards,
Thoth

**EDIT:** Just for the visualization purposes, I placed an output image (I just copy a background patch inside the circle.)

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by "Removing". Do you want to smooth the image?

Comment: I placed few more images for illustration. Any suggestions are highly appreciated, thanks for the interest:)

Comment: Please post a link to this image.  I have a few things I'd like to try.  Give us the original image.

Comment: Is this [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEzky.png) ok? Thanks for your interest!

Comment: @Thoth: Yes this is fine.  Thank you.  Give me a little bit to do this.

Comment: Your advise is higly appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S.A.

Yes you can simply accomplish your task using some morphological operations such as

- Opening
- Closing
- Dilation
- Erosion

and here is a simple code that may help you :

%After input image 'img' is read:

```
structuredElement1 = strel('disk',5);
structuredElement2 = strel('disk',3);
imageAfterErosion = imerode(img,structuredElement2);
imageAfterClosing = imclose(imageAfterErosion,structuredElement1);
imageAfterDilation = imdilate(imageAfterClosing,structuredElement1);        
imageAfterDilation = imdilate(imageAfterDilation,structuredElement1); 
imageAfterClosing = imclose(imageAfterDilation,structuredElement1);
binaryImage = imfill(imageAfterClosing, 'holes');  
imshow(binaryImage);
```

Comment: I think that does not return desired results, [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/be5c8.png). I have placed the initial image to verify it if you want. Please correct me If I am wrong:)

Comment: You can search for the Retinex algorithm+my code...it may help you.